# Cannot use MultipartFile in ModelAttribute with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, multipartform-data, webjars

My project is a spring-boot project using the parent dependency and thymeleaf with some webjars dependencies for the UI. I don't what am I missing.

I cannot use MultipartFile as a field of my ModelAttributeDto.

The exception occurs when I want to open the HTML. My problem is I want to use the validation of thymeleaf, and do not want to use the MultipartFile as simple `@RequestParam`.

The details are here, if you wish the pom.xml I would happily share it.

Thank you for your help.

dependencies besides the standard spring-boot 2.4.3 dependencies, pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
            <version>0.40</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
@Controller
public class UploadController {

    private final RestUploadService restUploadService;

    @GetMapping("/upload")
    public String load(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("uploadParams", new UploadParams());
        return "upload/upload";
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String upload(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("uploadParams") UploadParams uploadParams,
            BindingResult result,
            Model model
    ) {
        return "upload/upload";
    }
}
```

UploadParams:

```
@Data
public class UploadParams {

    String tableName;

    MultipartFile fileSource;
}
```

The HTML form:

```
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/upload}" th:object="${uploadParams}" method="post"
          onsubmit="this.submit_button.disabled = true;">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="tableName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Table name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input id="tableName" class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{tableName}"
                       placeholder="testExtendedTable"/>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('tableName')}" th:errors="*{tableName}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="fileSource" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">SDF file</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input id="fileSource" name="fileSource" class="form-control-file" type="file" placeholder="testExtendedTable" th:field="*{fileSource}"/>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('fileSource')}" th:errors="*{fileSource}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

The page can't even load, and I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'fileSource' of bean class [com.chemaxon.consultancy.codingexercise.adapters.api.dto.UploadParams]: Bean property 'fileSource' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:625) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:615) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:104) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:228) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:129) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
...
```

Comment: Try separating Mutipart filesource as separate param in your controller method, take out from UploadParams

Comment: @code_mechanic As a RequestParam it works but I don't have the functionality I need then. What am I missing, because it should work: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload

Comment: Yes, that's the part I am unsure about as well and trying to understand, may be that have to do with `ModelAttribute`, coincidentally I tried same thing in my code few days back but couo not make it work, so had to content with above said approach.

Comment: Also, I couldn't find much documentation around it, so that would need some digging.

Comment: The code seems correct. Can you try to avoid using Lombok on `UploadParams` to be sure that is not the issue?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe You were right somehow. It messed up something when I renamed my class. I gave my IDE (intellij idea) a hard reset and now it's working fine.